# Python: typing.cast vs built in casting

Tags: python, casting, mypy

Is there any difference between the typing.cast function and the built-in cast function?

```
x = 123
y = str(x)
```

```
from typing import cast
x = 123
y = cast(str, x)
```

I expected that mypy might not like the first case and would prefer the typing.cast but this was not the case.

Comment: `cast` doesn't _do_ anything. It's a no-op, purely for the type-checker: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c915f00ecaa1bf8adb3a4aa6aed4c3aaa95f8d8c/Lib/typing.py#L2211-L2219. `str` on the other hand actually tries to convert `x` to a string. Python doesn't actually have casting in the sense statically typed languages do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str(x)` returns a new `str` object, independent of the original `int`. It's only an example of "casting" in a very loose sense (and one I don't think is useful, at least in the context of Python code).

`cast(str, x)` simply returns `x`, but tells a *type checker* to pretend that the return value has type `str`, no matter what type `x` may actually have.

Because Python *variables* have no type (type is an attribute of a value), there's no need for casting in the sense that languages like C use it (where you can change how the contents of a variable are *viewed* based on the type you cast the variable to).